# standard / readable array declaration and using

Tags: php, arrays, code-standards

what in your opinion more standard / readable / efficient code of array declaration :

**one way :**

```
$days = array(1=>'Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
```

then use  : `$days[$value]`

**or the second way :**

```
$days = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
```

then use  : `$days[$value-1]`

update : i cant sure that the values be in [0-6] , because that i dont offer 3 way.

Comment: I'd go with the zero-based (2nd) in order to comply directly with the internal PHP representation (e.g., `date('w')`). Also, note the ISO-8601 numeric representation (`N`).

Comment: @jensgram: and what happens when the array has nothing to do with weekdays? ;)

Comment: @fabrik and where this array keys do come from?

Comment: @Shrapnel: Nobody said we must stick with this example. At least OP didn't.

Comment: @fabrik In general I would index my array corresponding to whatever I'm looking up. Thus, alternative 1 in general, which translates directly to alternative 2 when the data is (or ought to be) zero-based. **Also**, I'd judge by overall readability, not +/- 1 CPU cycle.

Comment: @jensgram: I think that's the same that i said/asked. CPU cycle vs readability? I'm sure it doesn't comparable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Definitely the first one (when keys are correctly defined).

In the second one you need to do a minus (extract) this <strike>is an unnecessary cpu cycle</strike> makes your code less readable and less maintenable.

Edit: I hope all of you lazy programmers are happy out there.

Comment: OH My Holy God! A whole CPU cycle! A disaster indeed.

Comment: Yeah and Achilles will never overtake Tortoise

Comment: Sorry, i'm definitely not a fan of dialogues like this.

Answer (score 3):

How about the 3rd way:

```
$days = array('Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
```

and access it as:

```
$days[$value]
```

by ensuring that `$value` has value between `[0,6]`

Comment: This will apply only when we stick with this example.

Comment: i cant its came from db query that Not up to me

Answer (score 2):

a funny one:

```
$days = array('Zer','Sun', 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat');
```

(a friend of mine used a month name "Nulleary" once)
but seriously, it depends on where this array does come from.
For this particular example it should be just `date("D",$tstamp);`

though the whole problem negligible to me.
I am often using just

```
$days = explode(" ",'Sun Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri Sat');
```

and find it very handy.

Comment: @stereofrog: Thanks, that was funny. It's interesting how lazy programmers lives here.

Comment: @stereofrog whoops! yu're right. Gonna check my server right now - it must be burning of such overload! :)